# How can i push my app to heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I created an app using the following:

```
(env) user:heroku create this-testingapp
(env) user:git add .
(env) user: git commit -m "app"
(env) user:git push heroku master
```

Here I noticed I made some mistakes I stopped the push midway  went to my heroku account delete this app then started over:

```
(env) user:heroku create secondattempt
(env) user:git add .
(env) user:git commit -m "another try"
(env) user:git push heroku master
```

but at last command I'm getting this error `remote: !   No such app as this-testingapp.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have deleted your app but the remote isn't deleted/changed yet. So you need to set new remote for the new app.
Type this in your terminal and try push the code again.

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/secondattempt.git
```

Edit: If you want to change the remote, (if it says remote already exists, then you might consider changing the remote name)

```
git remote rm heroku  
heroku git:remote -a secondattempt
```

Comment: Then you need to change the remote. Use the commands mentioned in the answer. I have edited the answer and added the additional commands.